# Notation for conditional probability

Tags: probability, notation, conditional-probability

Given $X = \{ x_1, x_2, \dots, \}$ and $Y = \{ y_1, y_2, \dots \}$ let $P(X,Y)$ be their joint probability. Conditioning $P(X, Y)$ on $y \in Y$ corresponds to looking at the distribution of the elements of $X$ when we disregard all elements of $Y$ other than $y$. This is achieved by normalizing $P(X,Y)$ by $P(Y = y) := \sum_{x \in X} P(X=x, Y=y_j)$. The resulting quantity is usually notated with $P(X \vert Y = y_j)$.

Now imagine that we only want to consider two elements $y_{j_1}$ and $y_{j_2}$ of $Y$. The joint distribution between $X$ and $Y$ that we obtain by disregarding all elements of $Y$ other than $y_{j_1}$ and $y_{j_2}$. I would like to notate this as follows
$$
P(X=x,Y=y_j \ \vert \ \{ y_{j_1}, y_{j_2} \})
:=
\begin{cases}
\frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(Y=y_{j_1}) + P(Y=y_{j_2})} & \text{if } y_j = y_{j_1}, y_{j_2} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

**Question 1**: Is there a standard way to notate this quantity?

**Question 2**: according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_a_random_variable) "*the conditional probability $P(X \mid Y)$ is a funciton of $Y$: e.g., if the function $g$ is defined as $g(y) = P(X \mid Y = y)$ then $P(X \mid Y) = g \circ Y$*". If we introduce a variable $Z$ defined as
$$
Z = \{ z_1, z_2, \dots \} := \{ \{ y_{j_1}, y_{j_2} \}: y_{j_1}, y_{j_2} \in Y, y_{j_1} \ne y_{j_2} \}
$$
and denote $g(z) = P(X,Y \mid z_i)$, $z_i \in Z$, according to the definition of $P(X,Y \mid \{ y_{j_1}, y_{j_2} \})$ above, would it make sense to denote $P(X,Y | Z) = g \circ Z$ even though $Z$ is not properly a random variable?

**Question 3**: would the notation $P(X \vert \{y_1, y_2 \}) := \sum_{y = y_1, y_2}$ be acceptable? And its "extended" version $P(X \vert Z)$?

**Example**: in the example in the figure below, $X$ can take three values $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$ (three positions on an axis), while $Y$ can take three colors ($\{blue, yellow, green\}$). For each $X_i$ I show only the possible outcomes of $Y$ (i.e. the values $y_j \in Y$ for which $p(x_i,y_j) \ne 0$). If for an $x_i$ there are two possible outcomes of $Y$, I group them with parentheses. The values of the joint probability $P(X,Y)$ are indicated by the fractions. For simplicity, in this example, I assume that the probabilities of the possible outcomes are the same, Panel A. This means that $P(x_1, blue) = 1/4$, $P(x_2, blue) = 1/4$, $P(x_2, green) = 1/4$, and so on. This is $P(X,Y)$.

In panel B, I show the distribution once we ignore all outputs of $Y$ other than $blue$. This would be the $P(X \mid Y = blue)$.

In panel C I show the bivariate distribution of X and Y, once all but two colors, ($blue$ and $yellow$) are discarded. This would be $P(X,Y \mid \{ blue, yellow \})$.

[image: Example]

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/461933/119261.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard notation for the right-hand side of your equation would be $\mathsf P(X=x\cap Y=y\mid Y\in\{y_1,y_2\})$. I’m not entirely convinced that this is really what you want, though; part of your post sounds as if what you really want is $\mathsf P(X=x\mid Y\in\{y_1,y_2\})$.

About the second question: $P(X\mid Y)$ does not denote all possible conditionings of $X$ on the elements of $Y$; it’s a random variable that’s a function of $Y$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_a_random_variable)). $P(X,Y\mid Z)$ can’t work like $P(X\mid Y)$ because whereas each outcome realizes a unique value of $Y$, each outcome realizes several pairs of values of $Y$, so you can’t have a function of “the” pair. You could of course have a function of the set of all pairs that are realized, but that would just be an unnecessarily fancy way of having a function of $Y$.

Comment: Thanks. To answer your questions. I am interested in both $P(X = x ,Y=y \mid Y \in \{ y_1, y_2 \})$ and its integration on $y = y_1, y_2$, which I would like to call $P(X=y \mid Y \in \{ y_1, y_2 \})$. Yes, that would be a function of the set of all pairs ($Z$ would be a set of sets). Isn´t that different than having a function of $Y$?

Comment: @Cesare: I'm not sure what you mean by "a function of the set of all pairs" here. You had proposed in the question to "introduce a variable $Z$ that is the set made of all pairwise subsets of $Y$", a concept that I don't understand but hadn't worried about much because you had noted yourself that "$Z$ is not properly a random variable". I had introduced in my answer "a function of the set of all pairs **that are realized**", something completely different. Which of these two concepts are you referring to here?

Comment: $P(X,Y \mid Z)$ would not be a random variable but would be a function of $Z$. That should be well defined. Or am I wrong? I am confused by your comment that "that would just be an unnecessarily fancy way of having a function of $Y$", cause it appears to me that $P(X,Y \mid Z)$ is a function of $Z$ and not of $Y$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, to clarify why I would like to introduce $Z$. The reason is that I am wondering whether I could define some information theoretic quantities like $H(X,Y \mid Z)$ or $H(X \mid Z)$...

Comment: @Cesare: You didn't answer my question. I still don't know what you mean by $Z$.

Comment: Oh sorry. I had not understood that you were asking that. $Z$ for me would be a set of subsets of $Y$: $Z := \{ \{ y_1, y_2\}, \{ y_1, y_3 \}, \dots \}$.

Comment: @Cesare: It's unfortunately still not clear from that whether $Z$ includes all pairs or just the pairs that include $y_1$. Here you write "a set", in the question you wrote "the set of all". Which one is it? I'm not going to continue this back and forth any longer, so please make sure that your next comment unambiguously answers that question that I posed a long way up.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It was not clear. I have expanded it in the question so that it should be clear now.

Comment: @Cesare: OK, so I take it that you were referring all along to the set of **all** pairs of possible values of $Y$. That is indeed not a fancy way of having a function $Y$ (which is how I described my suggestion of conditioning on the set of pairs **that are realized**). It's not clear to me what $P(X,Y\mid Z)$ would then refer to. You wrote that "$P(X,Y\mid Z)$ would not be a random variable but would be a function of $Z$". What does it mean to be a function of $Z$ if $Z$ is the set of **all** pairs of possible outcomes?

Comment: That's like saying that $Y$ in $P(X\mid Y)$ is the set of all possible outcomes of $Y$ (which it is not). Can you write down precisely what you want to denote by $P(X,Y\mid Z)$, just as you wrote down precisely what you wanted to denote by $P(X=x,Y=y\mid\{y_1,y_2\})$ in the question?

Comment: I have expanded the definition of $P(X,Y \mid Z)$ in the question using the information from the wikipedia link that you had mentioned. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Cesare: No, I don't think it does, but we seem to be moving closer to clarifying why it doesn't. You've now used a lower-case $z$. Lower-case letters are usually used to denote the values that the random variables with the corresponding upper-case letters take. But we agree that $Z$ is not a random variable. You didn't introduce $z$, and it's not clear what it could mean. The only thing I see that you might mean by it is $\{y_{j_1},y_{j_2}\}$. But that's not an outcome, it's a pair of outcomes, so it's not clear what $g\circ Z$ would mean. Perhaps try to spell out what you mean by $g\circ Z$.

Comment: I had introduced the $z$ in the definition of $Z$ (sorry, it is a bit hidden). Each $z$ is indeed a subset $\{ y_{j_1}, y_{j_2} \}$. In theory, one could look at $P(X \mid Y=y)$ as a special case of $P(X,Y \mid \{ y_{j_1}, y_{j_2} \} )$ in which $y_{j_1} = y_{j_2} = y$, i.e., $P(X,Y \mid Z)$ should reduce to $P(X \mid Y)$ if $Z := \{ \{ y_1, y_1 \}, \{ y_2, y_2 \}, \{ y_3, y_3 \} \dots \}$. Or am I missing something? It is clear to me that $P(X,Y \mid Z)$, unlike $P(X \mid Y)$ cannot be interpreted as a random variable.

Comment: @Cesare: It must be well hidden indeed, because I still don't see it. There is only a single occurrence of $z$ in the entire question. It seems to me from what you write that you didn't in fact intend $z$ to refer to the value of a random variable, and it's just a placeholder for the $z_1, z_2, \ldots$ that are the elements of $Z$. But that gets us back to the question what you mean by this. Your analogy between $Z$ and $Y$ is fatally flawed because $Y$ is not a constant set of all outcomes, so you can't define anything by that analogy.

Comment: The only concrete thing that you've written so far about what you mean by $P(X,Y\mid Z)$, other than invoking that analogy, is $g\circ Z$; I asked you to spell out what you mean by that, but you didn't.

Comment: I have added an index to $z$ ($z_i$) to make it more clear that I am referring to an element of $Z$ and made that explicit. To answer your second comment. One can looks at $P(X|Y)$ as to a function that returns the distribution of $X$ once you ignore all outcomes of $Y$ other than a chosen one. In other words you fix a $y \in Y$ and get a distribution for the elements of $X$. Can't one interpret $P(X,Y | Z)$ as the function that returns the distribution of the joint variable $XY$ when we ignore all outcomes of $Y$ but two?

Comment: The only difference should be that $P(X \mid Y)$ is also a random variable, while $P(X,Y \mid Z)$ is not. But each $P(X,Y \mid z_i)$ is the distribution of a discrete bivariate random variable just like $P(X \mid y_j)$ is the distribution of an univariate variable.

Comment: @Cesare: "Can't one interpret $P(X,Y\mid Z)$ as the function that returns the distribution of the joint variable $XY$ when we ignore all outcomes of $Y$ but two?" But which two?! That's the whole point. In $P(X\mid Y)$, it's clear which outcome, namely the value of $Y$. This is clear because $Y$ is a random variable. If you replace it by the constant set $Z$, then you haven't specified any outcome. I can only ask you once again to spell out what you mean explicitly.

Comment: The question was clear because it contained an equation that defined what you wanted to denote. I answered how I would denote that. Every since then, we've been going round in circles because you don't respond to my requests to define explicitly what you want to denote (not just in vague words like "all outcomes but two", but in a formal way that's as well-defined as the original equation in your question).

Comment: I will try with an example. I will post it at the bottom of the question. I hope that it makes it more clear. I am not trying not to answer your question, I am really not understanding your request. I hope that the example makes things clearer.

Comment: I have added it. I hope it helps clarifying what I mean.

Comment: @Cesare: I'm afraid this isn't leading anywhere. What you've explained in the example is the part that has been clear all along. You want to condition on $Y$ taking one of two outcomes. You defined that clearly in your original equation, and I wrote in my answer how I would denote that clearly defined probability. You can write it as $P(X,Y\mid\{\text{blue},\text{yellow}\})$ instead if you insist, but I think you'll find that people will understand you better if you use the standard notation $P(X,Y\mid Y\in\{\text{blue},\text{yellow}\})$.

Comment: Be that as it may, there's neither a $Z$ nor a $z$ in any of that. None of that does anything to help me understand why you want to replace the random variable $Y$ by the constant set $Z$ and what you mean by doing that. And now I'm giving up trying to understand. Best of luck with your endeavours.